# Specifying different page base classes for different directories in your web.config file

Tags: vb.net, class, web-config

I have a website (coded in vb.net) with an "admin" section (the admin section being a folder in the actual site)... So in every page of the site I'm using my own custom class as the page base (which has been set in the web.config file) but I want to inherit from different class for the files in the "admin" folder... Is there any way to inherit different classes for pages in different folders using the web.config or some other equally as global method? (meaning some other way than inheriting on a per page basis.)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a web.config file to any subfolder within the APS.NET web app. The values in this "sub-web.config" will take precidence over the "main" web.config.